# Customizing the comment_form() and comments.php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

For the life of me I can't seem to find any reliable or working sources. My current theme I'm working on doesn't have a comments.php file. I want to be able to customize the comments layout and look when I call it with comments_template(). But it seems to go to the default template which I can't find. I've tried using the comments.php from the twentytwenty theme but it throws a ton of errors and bugs my site out.

I want to just be able to locate the file that comments_template() is calling and edit that. Or the comments_form() more specfically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code as your `comments.php` file. It's a very barebones comments template to get you started, with some comments. The code is taken from a course by Zac Gordon. You should do a replace and search for wphierarchy and change it to your theme slug.

```
<?php

if ( post_password_required() ) {
    return;
}
?>

<div id="comments" class="comments-area">

    <?php
    // You can start editing here -- including this comment!
    if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <h2 class="comments-title">
            <?php
                printf( // WPCS: XSS OK.
                    esc_html( _nx( 'One thought on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', '%1$s thoughts on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'wphierarchy' ) ),
                    esc_html( _nx( 'One thought on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', '%1$s thoughts on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'wphierarchy' ) ),
                    number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ),
                    '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>'
                );
            ?>
        </h2><!-- .comments-title -->

        <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // Are there comments to navigate through? ?>
        <nav id="comment-nav-above" class="navigation comment-navigation" role="navigation">
            <h2 class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Comment navigation', 'wphierarchy' ); ?></h2>
            <h2 class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Comment navigation', 'wphierarchy' ); ?></h2>
            <div class="nav-links">

                <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Older Comments', 'wphierarchy' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Older Comments', 'wphierarchy' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Newer Comments', 'wphierarchy' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Newer Comments', 'wphierarchy' ) ); ?></div>

            </div><!-- .nav-links -->
        </nav><!-- #comment-nav-above -->
        <?php endif; // Check for comment navigation. ?>

        <ol class="comment-list">
            <?php
                wp_list_comments( array(
                    'style'      => 'ol',
                    'short_ping' => true,
                ) );
            ?>
        </ol><!-- .comment-list -->

        <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // Are there comments to navigate through? ?>
        <nav id="comment-nav-below" class="navigation comment-navigation" role="navigation">
            <h2 class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Comment navigation', 'wphierarchy' ); ?></h2>
            <h2 class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Comment navigation', 'wphierarchy' ); ?></h2>
            <div class="nav-links">

                <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Older Comments', 'wphierarchy' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Older Comments', 'wphierarchy' ) ); ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Newer Comments', 'wphierarchy' ) ); ?></div>

            </div><!-- .nav-links -->
        </nav><!-- #comment-nav-below -->
        <?php
        endif; // Check for comment navigation.

    endif; // Check for have_comments().


    // If comments are closed and there are comments, let's leave a little note
    if ( ! comments_open() && get_comments_number() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) : ?>

        <p class="no-comments"><?php esc_html_e( 'Comments are closed.', 'wphierarchy' ); ?></p>
    <?php
    endif;

    comment_form();
    ?>

</div><!-- #comments -->
```